# Ubuntu crashes frequently

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, cpu, crash

I recently moved from Windows to Ubuntu 14.04LTS 64-bit OS. Initially everything worked really well. However for the last couple of weeks Ubuntu started behaving crazy. The transition from good to crazy was slow :P. Now it crashes frequently and also I noticed a lag in it's boot time. Mostly the error is "Kernel Oops" and happens when I run Eclipse (I am always running Eclipse as a matter of fact). The entire system freezes and Ctrl+Alt+F1 doesn't open the terminal. I am not sure if I should do a fresh install or move to a 32-bit Ubuntu or even Xbuntu.

My system configuration is:

1. Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2350M CPU @ 2.30GHz 64-bit
2. Memory : 4Gigs

Below is a snippet of system logs:

[image]

Comment: Requirements should be more than enough for normal Ubuntu. But I can't help you, unfortunately...

Comment: This looks like a hardware problem (overheating, RAM broken, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Any suggestion that might help, like going to 32 bit or a repair ??